# Trouble with incompatible types

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and learning - so excuse the potentially silly question that this might be!

It's a simple Paper Rock Scissors game...

Using BlueJ I keep getting this error;

"incompatible types"

When running this code;

```
import comp102.*; 

import java.util.Scanner;


public class RPS{

    String paper = "paper";
    String rock = "rock";
    String scissors = "scissors";    

public void playRound(){

        String paper = "paper";
        String rock = "rock";
        String scissors = "scissors";    

        System.out.print ('\f'); // clears screen
        Scanner currentUserSelection = new Scanner(System.in);

        String enterText = null;
        System.out.println("Make your Selection; Paper, Rock or Scissors: ");
        enterText = currentUserSelection.next();

        System.out.println("enterText = " + enterText);

        if(enterText = paper){
            System.out.println("the IF Stmt is working");
        }

    }
```

The error is referring to this line "if(enterText = paper){"

Many Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. If your problem is solved you can mark one of the below answer as accepted see this link [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/203266)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign value in `if` which is not allowed

```
if(enterText = paper)  //here if expects expression which evaluates to boolean
```

Change to,

```
if(enterText == paper)
```

From [language specs jls-14.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9)

> The if statement allows conditional execution of a statement or a conditional choice of two statements, executing one or the other but not both.
>
> **The Expression must have type boolean or Boolean, or a compile-time error occurs.**

Instead of `==` operator use [String#equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) to compare the string.

```
if(enterText.equals(paper))  //this will compare the String values
```

**See also**

- [== and equals difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6864948/1031945)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if(enterText == paper)
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Change you `if{..}` condition as

```
if(enterText.equals(paper)){
  System.out.println("the IF Stmt is working");
}
```

Because you are assigning value within the if condition. So it is invalid.

Within if condition you have to check either it is **true** or **false** only.

**Syntax** for `if(){..}`

```
if(true or false) {
  //body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(enterText = paper){
            System.out.println("the IF Stmt is working");
 }
```

you should use == to check for equality. But since you are dealing with strings use equals() method

e.g.

```
 if(enterText.equals(paper)){
        System.out.println("the IF Stmt is working");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(enterText = paper){
  System.out.println("the IF Stmt is working");
}
```

Here you are using `=`  That is assignment operator.

Where `==`  is check for equality.

More over in java to check equality of Strings you should use `equals()`

**Reason:**[Why doesn’t == work on String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443201/why-doesnt-work-on-string/17443215#17443215)

So your code becomes,

```
if(enterText.equals(paper)){
      System.out.println("the IF Stmt is working");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(enterText = paper){
        System.out.println("the IF Stmt is working");
    }
```

should be

```
    if(enterText == paper){
        System.out.println("the IF Stmt is working");
    }
```